# How to output array of objects in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that looks like this:

```
$scope.locations    [

    {Kanaanbadet: {"name":"Kanaanbadet","image":"http://www.stockholm.se/Web/Core/Pages/Special/StreamServiceGuideImage.aspx?path=%2fWeb%2fCore%2fPages%2fSpecial%2fServiceGuideFile.aspx%3ffileid%3d14b313cb2b2f45e380eb88156c95b539","_cached_page_id":"4b71e342c82be9de1c74de3c2f57ea1c4dde8150","long":"17.85448","lat":"59.34966","url":"http://www.stockholm.se/-/Serviceenhetsdetaljer/?enhet=cf0a856830e4422cb55dcd60e8e6b40b"}},
    {Johannelundsbadet:{"name":"Johannelundsbadet","image":"http://www.stockholm.se/Web/Core/Pages/Special/StreamServiceGuideImage.aspx?path=%2fWeb%2fCore%2fPages%2fSpecial%2fServiceGuideFile.aspx%3ffileid%3d3e4c2056b5534cfc9b0799e2377b8ce4","_cached_page_id":"18cf34222d74612979afd945a925abc0bf16e44d","long":"17.98914","lat":"59.34098","url":"http://www.stockholm.se/-/Serviceenhetsdetaljer/?enhet=ebf8d49780224e908064551c35dbcca4"}},
    ...more items
]
```

I would lie to put out the name in a template within a foreach, and I would like to be able to reference the key.

```
<a  ng-href="#/{{location}}" class="location" ng-repeat="location in locations">{{location}}</a>
```

I can change the array around to look some other way, but I would like to keep it as an array so I can sort it and select items from the objects keys somehow. How should structure my array?

Comment: Could you just do `{{location.name}}`?

Comment: locations is the array, updating question.

Comment: `<a  ng-href="#/{{location}}" class="location" ng-repeat="(k,v) in locations">{{k}}</a>`

Comment: @wayne, that would work for an object with key values, key outputs the array-key (integer)

Comment: seiyria, nope, that would correspon to [{name: 'this thing'}, and I don't have a name-key in the objects, it's an object within an object.

Comment: No you can get the key like that. You can structure the half the array as data store. the other half as object. But I don't really like recommend that. another approach is use pure array of object as data store and use lodash `_.where` to find and select specific item.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to wrap this in two repeats:

```
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="location in locations">
      <a ng-href="#/{{item.url}}" class="location" ng-repeat="item in location">{{item.name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Maybe check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O75Wts9C7zcGr2ewZmxh?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest, I really dislike the way you have structured your object. The object should be anonymous, and name should be a property within it. That way, you could use `location.name`.

All that being said, you can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of the keys within the object.

```
<a ng-href="getKey(location)" 
   class="location" 
   ng-repeat="location in locations"> {{ getKey(location) }}
</a>
```

`getKey` would have to be a function on your scope:

```
 $scope.getKey = function(location){
    return Object.keys(location)[0];
 }
```

[Example plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zu4LcXIrbseWmGMuSkwV?p=preview)

**Note**: depending on desired browser support you might be better to iterate over the properties using a `for (key in location)` loop as some older browsers [won't support](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.keys) `Object.keys()`.